# Does latest version of Silverlight Depend in any way on .Net 3.0, 3.5?

Tags: silverlight

If you read the release notes from the [Feb 18th release of Silverlight](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/8/FD8F5947-78FF-40A5-9A34-5E35243C12E4/40115/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.html#Silverlight2GDR1), you will see a line that states:

***graceful failures when attempting to use features that require .Net Framework 3.0 or 3.5 on machines that do not have either framework installed***

What does this mean?  Surely Silverlight has no direct dependencies to the full .Net 3.0 or 3.5 framework. How could it when it runs on OS X and there are suppose to be no differences between running on Windows vs. OS X?

Anybody know something about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff - short answer: NO.  In the release notes this comment refers to UIAutomation implementations in Silverlight, not the core features.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the creditability of the site, but I found [this](http://maordavid.blogspot.com/2007/07/does-silverlight-require-net-framework.html) link that states:

> A common question about Silverlight is
>   - "Does .NET Framework installation is required in order to use
>   Silverlight?".  The answer to this is
>   no.
>
> A cross platform version of the .NET
>   Framework is included in the 4MB
>   Silverlight 1.1 download, which means
>   you do not need to have anything extra
>   installed on the client.
>
> The Silverlight version of the .NET
>   framework includes the same CLR engine
>   that ships with the full .NET
>   Framework, and a subset of the .NET
>   Framework namespace libraries.

I also found [this](http://silverlight2.blogspot.com/2008/01/silverlight-doesn-require-net-to-run.html) site that explains while .NET is not required at run time, it is required at build time.

Comment: I am aware of this, but I still wonder about the dependencies with the full framework. I assume there is something I'm missing or not understanding.

Comment: Yeah, I had an awfully difficult time digging up any concrete info on it with my 20-30 mins of googling.

Answer (score 0):

The silverlight runtime's basically a mini version of the .NET runtime.  If you run C# code that does something that needs a feature that's not part of the subset, it tries not to blow up now.

Various subsets of the .NET runtime have been ported to non-Windows systems, Silverlight's just the most widely-known one.

Comment: Sorry for beating this to death.  Silverlight should ALWAYS fail if it tries to run code that is not part of its own CLR. Whether that be .Net 3.0, 3.5, or any other language.  Was it somehow failing gracefully in the past if the 3.0 or 3.5 framework was found and not failing gracefully otherwise?